# Restart application hangman

Tags: java

I've got an restart button in my hangman application, but I have no clue on how to restart the application... can anyone help by giving me the right idea or pointing me to the right direction?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // Adds word to Words.txt
    if(e.getSource() == btnAddWord){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Words.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

            String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

            pw.println(word);
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ie){
            System.out.println("Error Thrown" + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // Restarts game
    if(e.getSource() == btnRestart){

    }
    // brings up Help screen
    if(e.getSource() == btnHelp){
        String message = "The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters and category of the word."
               + "\nIf the guessing player suggests a letter which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions."
               + "\nIf the suggested letter does not occur in the word, the other player draws one element of the hangman diagram as a tally mark."
               + "\n"
               + "\nThe game is over when:"
               + "\nThe guessing player completes the word, or guesses the whole word correctly"
               + "\nThe other player completes the diagram";
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message, "Help",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    //Exits application
    if(e.getSource() == btnExit){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the application state back to what it was when the user started? I mean that is the only answer here.

Comment: Why restart? Why not just re-initialize the hangman frame/window in a while loop, until the close button is pressed which should be handled and System.exit() should get called.

Comment: how would i re-initialize the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast and dirty way to do it would be to make an event handler or method that simply resets all the relevant variables to their initial values.